# How to set Maven as default type for the spring initialzr with Intellij version 2022.3

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, new-project

With the new Intellij version (2022.3) Maven is no longer the default type (is has selected Bradle- Groovy) for a Java Project when using the *spring boot initializr*.

This is extremely annoying since Maven used to be the default option.

I have searched through all relevant settings I could come up with, without any luck.

Can anyone explain how to change the default settings for the spring intializr?

Comment: This is just a datapoint, not sure if it's the root cause: On start.spring.io the default is also Gradle - Groovy, so i would assume, IntelliJ gets the default from there.

Comment: As I see in IntelliJ codebase, this cannot be changed directly. The pre-selected build system in the Spring initializer wizard has been changed in IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 because Gradle is now the default. See the related task at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-304284.

Comment: As a workaround, you could create a project with the options you need and save it as a template using `File | New Project Setup | Save Project as Template...`

Answer (score 2):

I also asked the question on IntelliJ support, and unfortunately this is not posible (yet)
As a consequence of my request, they have opened a feature request to allow for this:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-311387

If you, like me, are annoyed by this change please upvote the request